# Can I default every dbt command to cautious indirect selection?

Tags: dbt

I have a dbt project with several singular tests that `ref()` several models, many of them testing if a downstream model matches some expected data in the upstream. Whenever I build only another downstream model that uses the same upstream models, dbt will try to execute the tests with an out-of-date model. Sample visualization:

- Model "a" is an upstream view that only makes simply transformations on a source table
- Model "x" is a downstream reporting table that uses `ref("a")`
- Model "y" is another downstream reporting table that also uses `ref("a")`
- There is a test "t1" making sure every `a.some_id` exists in `x.some_key`
- Now if I run `dbt build -s +y`, "t1" will be picked up an executed, however "x" is out-of-date when compared to "a" since new data has been pushed into the source table, so the test will fail

If I run `dbt build -s +y --indirect-selection=cautious` the problem will not happen, since "t1" will not be picked up in the graph.

I want every single dbt command in my project to use `--indirect-selection=cautious` by default. Looking at the documentation I've been unable to find any sort of environment variable or YML key in dbt_project that I could use to change this behavior. Setting a new default selector also doesn't help because it is overriden by the usage of the `-s` flag. Setting some form of alias does work but only affects me, and not other developers.

Can I make every `dbt build` in my project use cautious selection by default, unless the flag `--indirect-selection=eager` is given?

Comment: I think you've researched all of your options pretty well. Setting up an environment variable and using an alias is pretty much the same thing, so you may just have to document the dev environment setup that all other developers should follow. The only other option would be to migrate to DBT Cloud and create the job configurations everyone shares...but I don't see that being much different than using selector configurations. Maybe reach out to the DBT team in their Slack channel and request support for this in dbt_project.yml.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a maintainer of dbt-core.

You can set an environment variable instead of the `--indirect-selection=buildable` CLI argument:

```
export DBT_INDIRECT_SELECTION=buildable
```

Here is an open issue to allow this to be set in `profiles.yml` also:

- https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/7518

Here's a visual aid for the different test nodes that would be selected by the different settings (`buildable` is my personal preference):

[image: dbt indirect_selection modes]